# Why Am I getting Overflow Error????? VBA/ ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please help me identify what I am doing wrong.  I am getting an overflow error with the section "weekendDays = weekenddays + 1 " highlighted.  The purpose of this code is to calculate the number of Tuesdays, Thursdays, Saturdays, and Sundays in 2 date ranges.

```
  '//////This is for Valley Estimate of Demurrage Days/////////////
Public Function ModWeekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, ByRef OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ByRef ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
Dim skips As Integer
Dim WeekendDays As Integer
Dim WeekendDays2 As Integer
'skips = 0
WeekendDays = 0
WeekendDays2 = 0


   Do
   If DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   End If
   Loop Until NotificationDate = OrderDate

   Do
   If DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays + 1
   End If
   Loop Until PlacementDate = ReleaseDate

   skips = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2
   skips = ModWeekdays(NotificationDate, OrderDate, PlacementDate, ReleaseDate)


End Function
```

Comment: Your loop appears to be infinte, in that you are not ever modifying `NotificationDate`.  In the above code, it will never equal `OrderDate` (unless they happen to be the same already).

Comment: You dont change either of `NotificationDate = OrderDate` so the loop runs forever, incrementing an integer until overflow?

Comment: how did i forget that....thanks

Comment: DateAdd("d", 1, NotificationDate) = NotificationDate   would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't incrementing your variable, so you're in an infinite loop.  This should fix some of the back-and-forth from our comments.

Your function should look like this:

```
'//////This is for Valley Estimate of Demurrage Days/////////////
Public Function ModWeekdays(ByRef NotificationDate As Date, ByRef OrderDate As Date, ByRef PlacementDate As Date, ByRef ReleaseDate As Date) As Integer
Dim skips As Integer
Dim WeekendDays As Integer
Dim WeekendDays2 As Integer
'skips = 0
WeekendDays = 0
WeekendDays2 = 0


   Do
   If DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", NotificationDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays = WeekendDays + 1
   End If
   ' This is the increment line you were missing
   NotificationDate = DateAdd("d", 1, NotificationDate)
   Loop Until NotificationDate = OrderDate

   Do
   If DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 0 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 2 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 4 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays2 + 1
   ElseIf DatePart("w", PlacementDate) = 6 Then
   WeekendDays2 = WeekendDays + 1
   End If
   ' This is the increment line you were missing
   PlacementDate = DateAdd("d", 1, PlacementDate)
   Loop Until PlacementDate = ReleaseDate

   ' No need to set Skip equal to the sum, just set ModWeekdays equal to it 
   '   so you can return the value.
   ' Also, remove that last line, which re-calls the function and causes an infinite loop
   ModWeekdays = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2

End Function
```

Then, you would call it from your button (or whatever you're doing to run this function) like this:

```
Dim TotalDaysToSkip as Integer

TotalDaysToSkip = ModWeekdays(Date1, Date2, Date3, Date4)
```

Comment: Did you try flipping them around, as I have above?  In your formula you're trying to add a day to a variable first, in mine you're setting the variable equal to the DateAdd statement.

Comment: actually i'm still getting overflow after making your suggested corrections

Comment: OK, the problem is that the last line calls the function again, and this time NotificationDate is already equal to OrderDate.  So, the first runthrough increments NotificationDate to be OrderDate + 1, and the loop continues to infinity.  Why do you need that last line?

Comment: I was told to add that earlier in another question on this website.  I figured it was a way to "export" the final number of days to my access application.

Comment: Try removing it and I think you should be OK.  The line directly above it, "skips = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2" will give you your value.  If you want to return the value, change it to "ModWeekdays = WeekendDays + WeekendDays2", and run the whole thing by putting something like "X = ModWeekdays(Date 1, Date 2, Date3, Date4)".  This way, 'X' will be set equal to ModWeekdays from your function's last line.  I know that's kind of murky, hopefully you followed what I was saying.

Comment: See my edited answer.  This should (hopefully) spell it out and provide working code for you.